# EF core query could not be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wildcard, sql-like

I am trying to develop some dynamic type of code that needs the following complicated query to run.

```cs
IEnumerable<string> searchKeys = search.KeySearch.Split(',').Select(key => key.Trim());
var searchedIds = _dbContext.Keys
    .Where(key => searchKeys.Any(searchKey => EF.Functions.Like(key.Name, searchKey)))
```

Actually I want to find the rows containing one of the searchKeys inside. For example if I have searchKeys like this:

```cs
var searchKeys = ["name_%", "last_x%];
```

then I want to find the row for example with name `name_alex` or with name `last_xaka`.
But ef cores says that it couldn't be translated and suggests either to write a translatable query or do the query in client (which is not appropriate in my problem).

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(k => __searchKeys_0
> .Any(searchKey => __Functions_1
> .Like(
> matchExpression: k.Name,
> pattern: searchKey)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client
> evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

So I want to change the query to a translatable one but I don't know that what is the problem and no clue to start fixing it.

Comment: Hi,

try write SQL and use method _dbContext.Keys.FromSqlRaw(...)

Comment: Thanks @MartinGluch for your solution. I will try this one, but I think it will be good if I could fix it using the LINQ.

Comment: Can you please try whether `dbContext.Keys.Where(key => searchKeys.Contains(key.Name, searchKey))` can be translated?

Comment: @mu88 your code is syntactically wrong. Because the `Contains` method gets value and comparer. But instead I've tried `_dbContext.Keys.Where(key => searchKeys.Any(searchKey => key.Name.Contains(searchKey)))` and it doen not work too (although it also does not solve my problem).

Comment: Sorry for the wrong code, I meant `dbContext.Keys.Where(key => searchKeys.Contains(key.Name))`. I know that the `LIKE` is still missing, just to have a starting point.

Comment: Of course @mu88 it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the following solution should at least work:

```cs
var searchKeys = search.KeySearch.Split(',').Select(key => key.Trim());

var queries = new List<IQueryable<Key>>();
foreach (var searchKey in searchKeys)
{
    queries.Add(_dbContext.Keys.Where(k => EF.Functions.Like(k.Name, searchKey)));
}

var finalQuery = queries[0];
for (var i = 1; i < queries.Count; i++)
{
    finalQuery = finalQuery.Union(queries[i]);
}

var filteredKeys = finalQuery.ToList();
```

I assume the code to be very unefficient because it will result in multiple `UNION` statements.

A more performant option would be to build an expression tree `Expression<Func<Key, bool>>` that basically produces the following result: `.Where(k => EF.Functions.Like(k.Name, searchKey[0]) || ... ||  EF.Functions.Like(k.Name, searchKey[5]))`.

Comment: Although your solution does not address the problem with "EF core query could not be translated", but it solved my problem very very well. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure, it was a pleasure to help you 